# HTML File API Object Read Issues

Tags: javascript, fileapi

**Original Question**
Why can I not loop through a File API object. The File API states that it is a read only interface, yet I'm unable to read using a traditional for loop. Ive read the https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-file but no further insight. The objective is inject the file into my own file class and then in the constructor loop through the file object to set the properties in the new file class e.g. file name, size, etc. The problem is the I'm unable to read the properties of the HTML File API object using hasOwnProperty() and so I need to forgo validating property or I need to cast it to an array.

**EDIT (A SOLUTION):**

Still don't have a clear answer, but the solution as I see it is to create a File class, which extends custom file utilities for size, progress, etc.

```
import utils from '../utilities/utils';
import _FileError from '../utilities/FileError';

class _File {

    constructor(file) {
        utils.defineNonEnumerable(this, 'errors', []);
        utils.defineNonEnumerable(this, 'file', null);
        utils.defineNonEnumerable(this, 'valid', null);

        if ((this.valid = !(file instanceof File))) {
            // Set file properties
            this.id = utils.uid();
            this.file = file;
            this.fileType = this.file.type;
            this.name = file.fileName || file.name;
            this.size = file.size;

            // Set state properties
            this.aborted = false;
            this.completed = false;
            this.status = null;
            this.category = null;
            this.category = null;
        } else {
            this.errors = new _FileError(file,new TypeError());
        }
    }
}

export default _File;

utils.extend(_File.prototype, {

    getSize: function () {
        var size = 0
        this._eachAccess(function (file) {
            size += file.size
        }, function () {
            size += this.size
        });
        return size
    }
});
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION EXAMPLE**

```
// Note the same applies to e.target.files as they are all HTML File API

onDragDrop (e) {
    for (let i = 0; i < e.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
        this.files.push(new File(files[i]));
    }
}
```

my files class

```
class File {

    constructor(file) {
        this.file = file;

        // this works i.e. assigns name to name property
        this.name = file.name;

        // deconstruction works i.e. assigns name to name property
        const {name} = file;
        this.name = name;

        // the result if type  object
        console.log(typeof file);

        // this returns false
        console.log(typeof file.hasOwnProperty('name'));

        // this does not work as expected on an object
        for (var property in file) {
            // hasOwnProperty returns false
            if (file.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                this.file[property]
            }
        }

      // this works and sets properties on the object, but feels dodgy 
      // given that none of the object properties are read by hasOwnProperty() 
        for (var property in file) {
            if (typeof file[property] !== "function") {
                this[property] = file[property]
            }
        }


        console.error('IMAGE MODEL',this);

    }
}
```